# Vim, in normal mode, prints command to screen at cursor, rather than executing [pic]

Tags: vim

Sometimes, when in normal mode, I'll execute a command like `j`. Instead of scrolling my cursor, vim will hang for a bit and print the letter j on the screen. Eventually it'll wake up and execute. See the pic, below:

[image]

I've disabled all highlighting thinking it was my problem. I've also scoured the internet and added all sorts of commands to my .vimrc to speed things up, but to no avail.

I've only been using vim for about two weeks, but it's unusable like this :( Any help would be much, much appreciated!

FYI - I'm on a new surface book 2 using WSL, but had the same problems on my old mac book pro.

.vimrc, below:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTree' }

Plug 'fatih/vim-go'
Plug 'fatih/molokai'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'nsf/gocode', { 'rtp': 'vim', 'do': '~/.vim/plugged/gocode/vim/symlink.sh' }

"Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }

Plug 'wikitopian/hardmode'

call plug#end()

" General VIM
set clipboard=unnamed
set number
set nocursorcolumn
set ttimeoutlen=100
set ttyfast
set lazyredraw
set nocursorline
set norelativenumber
syntax sync minlines=256
set synmaxcol=128
set re=1

" SirVer/ultisnips
" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use
" https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
" let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
" let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
" let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
" let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 3

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
" let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
" let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir="~/.vim/UltiSnips/snips"

" NERDTree
let NERDTreeShowHidden = 1

" fatih/vim-go
set autowrite

" mappings
map <C-n> :cnext<CR>
map <C-m> :cprevious<CR>
nnoremap <leader>a :cclose<CR>
autocmd FileType go nmap <leader>b  <Plug>(go-build)
autocmd FileType go nmap <leader>r  <Plug>(go-run)
autocmd FileType go nmap <leader>t  <Plug>(go-test)
autocmd FileType go nmap <Leader>c <Plug>(go-coverage-toggle)
autocmd Filetype go command! -bang A call go#alternate#Switch(<bang>0, 'edit')
autocmd Filetype go command! -bang AV call go#alternate#Switch(<bang>0, 'vsplit')
autocmd Filetype go command! -bang AS call go#alternate#Switch(<bang>0, 'split')
autocmd Filetype go command! -bang AT call go#alternate#Switch(<bang>0, 'tabe')

" prefs
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
let g:go_fmt_autosave = 1 
"let g:go_metalinter_autosave = 1
"let g:go_metalinter_autosave_enabled = ['gofmt', 'vet', 'golint', 'errcheck']
let g:go_metalinter_enabled = ['vet', 'golint', 'errcheck', 'gas', 'deadcode', 'gotype']
let g:go_metalinter_deadline = "90s"
let g:go_addtags_transform = "camelcase"
" let g:go_highlight_types = 1
" let g:go_highlight_fields = 1
" let g:go_highlight_functions = 1
" let g:go_highlight_structs = 1
" let g:go_highlight_interfaces = 1
" let g:go_highlight_methods = 1
" let g:go_highlight_operators = 1
" let g:go_highlight_extra_types = 1
" let g:go_highlight_build_constraints = 1
let g:go_auto_type_info = 1
let g:go_auto_sameids = 1
let g:go_list_type = "quickfix"
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.go setlocal noexpandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 

" color scheme
let g:rehash256 = 1
let g:molokai_original = 1
colorscheme molokai
set term=screen-256color
hi QuickFixLine term=reverse ctermbg=52

" statusline
" set rtp+=/Users/adamhanna/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/
set rtp+=~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/

" Always show statusline
set laststatus=2

" " Use 256 colours (Use this setting only if your terminal supports 256
" colours)
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: Do you happen to use [mosh](https://mosh.org) with typing prediction enabled over a slow connection?

Comment: No, I'm on my own machine, but thanks for the help!

Comment: There's something in my `fatih/vim-go` that's slowing it down. Disabling it completely stops the issues. I'm trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found my answer. It was indeed my `fatih/vim-go` package. Specifically, I had to comment out the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
# let g:go_auto_type_info = 1
```